# incorrect web service method URL

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I've built a simple web method in WebService1.asmx that checks the strength of a password. I'm trying get the method to work with javascript on a string in an html input field.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public string PasswordCheck(string str) {
  bool flag1 = false;
  bool flag2 = false;
  int k = 0;

  while ((flag1 == false || flag2 == false) && k < str.Length) {
    if ((str[k] <= 'z' && str[k] >= 'a') || (str[k] <= 'Z' && str[k] >= 'A'))
      flag1 = true;
    else if (Char.GetNumericValue(str[k]) <= 9 && Char.GetNumericValue(str[k]) >= 0)
      flag2 = true;
    k++;
  }

  if (flag1 && flag2)
    return "Strong";
  else
    return "Weak";
}
```

and here's the javascript section:

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
   var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

   function testFunc(str) {
     httpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (httpReq.status = 200 && httpReq.readyState == 4)
         document.getElementById("span1").innerHTML = httpReq.responseText;
     }
     httpReq.open("GET", "WebService1.asmx/PasswordCheck?str=" + str, true);
     httpReq.send();
   }
</script>
```

I'm getting the following error when activating testFunc with a keystroke: "Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/PasswordCheck'". What seems to be the problem here? Am I perhaps typing the URL in httpReq.open() incorrectly?

Comment: (Unrelated) Better practice to POST a password candidate

Comment: Yeah I know, I wrote a POST version as well. The point of this was to practice AJAX, password check was just the first thing that came to my mind.